# How to read a text file and search for a certain string before a colon and then show the content after the colon?

Tags: php, regex, file, preg-match, file-get-contents

I have a file that contains something like this:

```
test:fOwimWPu0eSaNR8
test2:vogAqsfXpKzCfGr
```

I would like to be able to search the file for say `test` and it set the string after the `:` to a variable so it can be displayed, used etc.

Here is the code I have so far for finding 'test' in the file.

```
$file = 'file.txt';
$string = 'test';

$searchFile = file_get_contents($file);
if (preg_match('/\\b'.$string.'\\b/', $searchFile)) {
    echo 'true';
    // Find String
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just get your file into an array with `file()` and then simply `preg_grep()` all lines, which have the search string before the colon.

```
<?php

    $file = "file.txt";
    $search = "test";

    $lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    $matches = preg_grep("/^" . preg_quote($search, "/") . ":(.*?)$/", $lines);
    $matches = array_map(function($v){
        return explode(":", $v)[1];
    }, $matches);

    print_r($matches);

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => fOwimWPu0eSaNR8 )
```

Comment: Your response works, but it only works for the first line in the file, it won't work for any lines after, is there a reason as to why?

Comment: @jdnoon It still works, but the index is the line number in the file. So if you want to reindex the array just simply wrap an array_values() call around the array_map() call