# How to read a file specific text with fopen and fget

Tags: php

I have a config.txt file that stores credentials to a server. I need to read the credentials from specific points[image]

From the above pic I need to read the three variables only starting after the two :: position

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a text file and search for a certain string before a colon and then show the content after the colon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433793/how-to-read-a-text-file-and-search-for-a-certain-string-before-a-colon-and-then)

Comment: If you have control over what the text file contains, consider rewriting it to use standard JSON or ini format, and then you can use JSON.parse() or read_ini_file()  php functions to get the data easily into an array.

Comment: @Cuagau i have control over the file how can i use ini or json

Comment: In that case Json is the way to go in my opinion. It has less overhead than preg_match and gives you all three variables at the same time.

Comment: @Andreas how should i implement json

Comment: Json is a string format that can be converted to object or array. It starts with a { and ends with }. In between items are comma separated. And each item is held inside " ". See example. https://3v4l.org/BOYmP I don't want to make it an answer as I think it's @Cuagaus answer.

Comment: Simply create a json object and store these as key value store , some frameworks like fuel php, go for XML, or even php based config. Last one is the most easiest

Comment: @Cuagau are you not going to post it as an answer?

Comment: @Cuagau post it as an answer

Answer (score 4):

Just use regex:

```
<?php
$pattern = '/server_name::(.*)$/';
$file = '/Your/file/path/here';
preg_match($pattern, file_get_contents($file), $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

The first match should be the server name: `$matches[0]`

Comment: Refresh the answer, and you should have some clarity. Look at the docs for `preg_match` for more details, but essentially `$matches` is a variable that will contain an array of matches once the function has returned. `file_get_contents` is a function for retrieving the contents of a file.

Comment: There is one undefined, that is $file, but that is undefined because it's undefined in your question. Your question only state, *I have a txt file*. How are we supposed to define that? $matches is where the function places the result as Jordan wrote in the answer. Read the PHP manual about preg match for further information.

Comment: @JordanS okay let me try and implement this i will update you if ti works

Comment: @Andreas jordan solution is now defined